# How can I establish a permanent travel route between two planes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, planes

I have a character who wishes to establish a permanent connection between the material plane and another plane of existence. This other plane happens to be a Demiplane.

He must be able to travel back and forth between the Demiplane and the material plane at least once per day.

Said character is not a spellcaster. He is, however, of a high level, and has significant resources available to him.

A "good" way to travel between the planes would

- Allow more than just one character to make the trip
- Not carry a trips/day restriction (or other usage restriction)
- Be cheap to set up

The way to travel may *not* entail expending permanent resources (GP or XP) for each trip, as it will be regularly used for a long period of time.

So far, the best I have found are Planar Ring Gates, a 200k GP wondrous item from the Planar Handbook.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a feat called [Create Portal](http://dndtools.eu/feats/forgotten-realms-campaign-setting--19/create-portal--486/) from the *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting (pg. 34)*.

> You have learned the ancient craft of creating a portal, a permanent magic device that that instantaneously transports those who know its secrets from one locale to another. Faerun is riddled with portals.
>
> Prerequisite: Craft Wondrous Item (PH)
>
> Benefit: You can create any portal whose prerequisites you meet.
>
> Crafting a portal takes one day for each 1,000 gp in its base price. To craft a portal, you must spend 1/25 of its base price in XP and use up raw materials costing half of this base price. See Chapter 2: Magic for details of portal creation. Some portals incur extra costs in material components or XP as noted in their descriptions. These costs are in addition to those derived from the portals base price.

From *Chapter 2: Magic (pg. 61)*:

> Base Cost: The builder must spend 50,000 gp on raw materials to create a single, continuously active one-way *portal* [...]  The builder can create a second *portal* at the destination point, making a two-way *portal* for half price (25,000 gp, fifty days, 2,000 XP).

So in total this would craft a two-way *portal* for 75,000 gp and 6,000 XP, which is cheaper than your wondrous item, depending on how you valuate XP.  There are also plenty of rules for restricting access, creating larger or smaller *portals*, and anything else in that section of the *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting*.

Note that in order for a *portal* to be crafted between planes, the creator must know the *gate* spell.

As far as your further specifications (*pg. 59*):

> Unless the builder has preset some limit, any number of creatures can pass through a *portal* each round.  A creature using a *portal* can take along up to 850 pounds of gear.  In this case, gear is anything a creature carries or touches.

Comment: Great find. I was looking into what it'd cost to craft a continuous Gate item, and it worked out to a market value of 1.2 million gp. Yours is better. :)

Comment: @Tridus :)  I played in a very long-term game once where stuff like this was an issue.  Believe me, we tried to find the most economical ways to get stuff done.  The GM hated us.  Haha

Comment: Nice. This looks like something I could use. Will keep it open for a bit longer, but this is an accept-worthy candidate!

Comment: This feat is also found in the Stronghold Builder's Guidebook, which was a 3.0 resource that (to my knowledge) was never updated to 3.5rd edition, and so is presumably still valid.

Answer (score -3):

Since the character has significant resources available and the Create Portal feat named by @JeffGohlke is not very useful on the long run, he could instead pay a guy with the feat to open a permanent portal for him.

The rules for creating permanent portals are in the Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting, page 61.

---

A cheaper but cheesier alternative would be to pay for the creation of a particular structure (I'm hunting for the precise name of the thing and where it's detailed) which is able to cast a spell (let's say teleport) at the price of feeding it magic item uses. The cheesiness is in the fact that you can use cheap, infinite uses wondrous items to feed it, making this into a free teleport generator.

Comment: Plane Shift is only 5th level, so paying someone actually is practical for some amount of time. That said, the question stated he didn't want each specific trip to consume resources. So the normal rules for paying a caster would rule that option out.

Comment: I'm not proposing that option, @Tridus