# Are there methods to allow players to create permanent gates between planes/demiplanes?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, planes, portals

My players are wondering if they can create permanent ways between their demiplanes (created by the [*demiplane*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/demiplane) spell) and between the planes the campaign takes place in. They, over time, have made many demiplanes, each one having a specific purpose, and they want to bring them together into a single demiplane, or at least connect them for easy travel between them.

If there are no methods to do that, is there a way to key the cubic gate to new planes/demiplanes, as well as a specific location, or key an [*amulet of the planes*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/amulet-of-the-planes) to a specific location on the planes? One thing I think could be an option is using teleportation circles as permanent ‘landing pads’. I'll accept homebrew suggestions that have successfully been tested at your table.

Comment: Related on [Can I get trapped in my own demiplane?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71864/can-i-get-trapped-in-my-own-demiplane), [What is the nature of a demiplane?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71955/what-is-the-nature-of-a-demiplane)

Comment: No, I’m asking if there is a way to create permanent gates between planes, not for a method to leave them when the portal from the demiplane spell vanishes

Comment: @EjSizemore Naut was just leaving a related link. All that means is that people who are interested in this question may also be interested in those ones. It is a way to link similar questions together.

Comment: One related question I’ve looked at was https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/28580/how-can-i-establish-a-permanent-travel-route-between-two-planes?rq=1

Comment: That answers it for the most part, thank you, just need to come up with an idea on how to let them force a specific plane for the womw now. Thanks